# How to resolve in django AttributeError: module 'learning_logs.views' has no attribute 'new_entry'

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

This is my views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Create your views here.
from .models import Topic
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm


def index(request):
    """The home page for learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')


def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""

    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)


def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)


def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topics')
        # Display a blank or invalid form.
        context = {'form: form'}
        return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)
    
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)


    if request.method != 'POST':
    # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic_id)
            
     # Display a blank or invalic form.
     context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
     return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

Here is my urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
# Home page
path('', views.index, name="index"),
# Page that shows all topics.
path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),

# Detail page for a single topic.
path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
# Page for adding a new topic,\
path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),

# Page for adding a new entry
path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
```

What I've done is copied this code from the textbook 'Python Crash Course' third edition. When I run python manage.py runserver I expect  the browser to go to localhost:8000/new_topic.

Comment: From the way you wrote your question it looks like if everything was in the same file (`urls.py` and `views.py` code looks like all in one file). To make it easier to understand what's going edit your question: (1) divide the code for each file to be a separate block of code, adding a comment at the top explaining which file it is `# views.py` (2) share the full text of your error (usually it will also indicate in which specific file/line the error happened) (3) It would also help to see the structure of your folders (like a tree of your project - in case you are importing from the wrong file)

Comment: Include the full error traceback in your question.

Comment: In the `new_topic` view, you have `context = {'form: form'}`. That should be `context = {'form': form}`.

I don't know if that will fix the error you're seeing, though. Are you sure you have saved your views.py file since adding the `new_entry()` function?